# BigQuery imports - CS file not found

Tags: google-bigquery

Our system runs BQ csv file (~8Mb) import from CS every 10 minutes. But today at least 4 times error occured: "Not found: Google Storage File ...". I've double checked the file on CS and download it with no problems. I've tried to (re)start BQ import (job_610b149c0d9041b7a3145ee245b80653), got "not found..." again. All other imports (hundreds of them) are just fine.

We're using GAE (java) for staging csv files on CS and then triggering import jobs (GAE -> CS -> BQ). In general system works fine but it's not very reliable. So, I'm fighting with gaps (missing data) or sometimes duplicates almost every day. Are there any other ways (good practices) of importing "constant flow" of data into BQ? Streaming?

Once we have data in BQ table, things become much easier. BigQuery is really great product! Thanks, sasa

Comment: I'm having the same issue today. We download and process files from GAE and store them onto Cloud Storage. We then kick off a BQ job with to consume those files for us. We randomly get errors of "File Not Found" and the job failing.

Comment: This should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fixed. There was a configuration issue that caused some Cloud Storage files to be inaccessible between around 5 PM last night and 10:15 am this morning (PST). Please ping this thread if you have any further issues.

Comment: import job (job_c4d1a16f62144cdbabc703fc902c24d9) reports following errors: 
"Too many columns: expected 28 column(s) but got 29 column(s). For additional help: http://goo.gl/RWuPQ" ...
When I repeat import of the same file (unmodified) few hours later everything was OK (job_05f6217c70d44a10b183e026733ddfc0)